# Updating OpenSSH on Amazon Linux - Amazon repository out of date

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

I read today that there's a [significant vulnerability](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.1p2) in OpenSSH, which is fixed by the latest version, 7.1p2. According to [this story](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/01/14/openssh_is_wide_open_to_key_theft_thanks_to_roaming_flaw/) your private key is vulnerable to disclosure.

I'm using the latest Amazon Linux AMI, and everything is up to date against Amazon's repository.

```
[root@aws /]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
```

Here's the list of what packages are available in the Amazon yum repository

```
yum list | grep openssh

openssh.x86_64                      6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-clients.x86_64              6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-server.x86_64               6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1            @amzn-updates
openssh-keycat.x86_64               6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1            amzn-updates
openssh-ldap.x86_64                 6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1            amzn-updates
```

It seems like the Amazon repository is around two years behind on OpenSSH updates. I have read that some vendors back port updates to older versions of OpenSSH, so this might not be an issue, or Amazon may address it relatively soon.

Questions:

- Is this really a problem?
- If it's a problem, what's the best way to update? I would typically find another yum repository, increase its priority, and update from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's really a problem, if you ever ssh to a machine that an attacker might control.

Until Amazon updates its package, you can stop the bug from affecting you by adding the line `UseRoaming no` to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on any machine from which you will be using the ssh client.

Comment: I guess given I don't ssh to any machine from my server it's unlikely to be an issue, but I wonder if there are other affected vectors. How about if my email server makes a secure connection to a compromised mail server? Connecting to secure upstream resources? I guess I mostly wonder why Amazon's OpenSSH version is so old.

Comment: As you suggested in your question, Amazon backport security fixes. Version 6.6.1p1-22.58.amzn1 isn't old at all; it was released last month as a security fix. It's based on an older version of openssh because that makes it easier to keep it stable, secure and supported, since they don't run the risk of introducing new bugs that have been added to new openssh releases.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Scott. It makes it more difficult to work out if you're up to date, especially when the version information says Jan 2015.

Comment: Accepted answer was posted on Jan 14 2016. How long does it take for Amazon to update it's package? Today (Aug 2nd 2017) I asked similar question at SOF - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470456/how-to-upgrade-openssh-from-6-6-1p1-to-version-7-2p2-on-amazon-linux

Comment: As the comment above says, Amazon backports security fixes into their package. They're up to OpenSSH 6.6.1p1-33.66.amzn1 now.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded OpenSSH 7.4 to 9.3 on amazon Linux 2 and followed the below steps for the same

```
  yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
  yum install pam-devel libselinux-devel
  tar zxvf openssh-9.3p1.tar.gz 
  cd openssh-9.3p1/
  ./configure 
  ls -l /usr/local/etc
  ./configure  --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
   make
   make install
```

while running "make install" you will get the below error comment both the line and re-run the "make install"

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 77: Unsupported option GSSAPIAuthentication
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 78: Unsupported option GSSAPICleanupCredentials
```